# Java adding symbols into derby query results?

Tags: java, eclipse, unicode, internationalization, derby

I have an Apache Derby Database, that I dumped from a sql file, however for some reason when I query the database in java, some unique symbols that I need in the database are prefixed with other symbols, or just don't turn out right. I also have a special font that I use, so I'm wondering if that's the problem, however when I had an sqlite database, it ran perfectly. When I query the database from the ij command line tool, everything is fine. I'm not sure what's going on.

edited from comments, relevant info.

> when I query for the column that should have a character like µ, it gives the correct character over ¬ (the character is like an accent, it should appear over the character) but the ¬ should not appear.

[image: Here's a picture for more clarity]

> In arial, a "normal" font, the query looks like this "rwmklI mhlw 3 An¬µdu", while from the ij tool, the query is "rwmklI mhlw 3 Anµdu" which is the correct way, and the way it is in the database.  the query is like this:

```
SELECT Gurmukhi, English, ShabadID FROM Shabad WHERE FirstLetterStr LIKE '%"+numberquery(text)+"%'
```

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: Sounds like a character encoding issue.

Comment: @DavidB ok, so when I query for the column that should have a character like µ, it gives the correct character over ¬ (the character is like an accent, it should appear over the character) but the ¬ should not appear.

Comment: @Michael But why would it work when querying the sqlite database and not the derby database? or are you saying the database itself won't allow characters like that? I have things like ¥¬ßƒø√ showing up.

Comment: @Mukhi It might be that each database uses a different default character encoding for storing strings in the database.  I would check the docs to see if you can explicitly set the char encoding they use.

Comment: @Michael thanks, I will check that out, but I'm not sure what encoding I have to use for this. those symbols should be showing up according to the font I've used, but I guess the unicode encoding is making them show up as is?

Comment: @Mukhi Can you post a screenshot of what the text looks like in a "normal" font like Arial?

Comment: "rwmklI mhlw 3 Anµdu" is what it would say

Comment: @Michael Sorry forgot to tag you

Comment: @Mukhi Is that what it looks like *without* the extra characters?  What does it look like *with* the extra characters when it is retrieved from Derby?

Comment: @Mukhi Also, how are you retrieving this string from the Derby database?  Can you post the Java code?  What happens when you just output the string to stdout using `System.out`?

Comment: @Michael I use the same expression to retrieve from derby that I do from eclipse. that it the way it should be, and the way derby's ij tool returns it. there's no difference between the way I query the db in java vs. how I query in the ij tool. Give me a couple minutes and I'll check what it says through the System.out.print command.

Comment: @Michael java outputs rwmklI mhlw 3 An¬µdu so it added the ¬ character for some reason the query is like this "SELECT Gurmukhi, English, ShabadID FROM Shabad WHERE FirstLetterStr LIKE '%"+numberquery(text)+"%'" don't worry about the method, it's got no impact on the database.

Comment: @Mukhi I'm not sure.  The `derby.ui.codeset` system property is used by `ij` to set the character encoding, but I don't think that property is used by Derby itself, it's just used by the `ij` tool.  You can try setting it when you startup your Java application:  `java -Dderby.ui.codeset=UTF8 com.company.Class`.  Docs: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/dev/tools/rtoolsijpropref97949.html

Comment: I just used the replaceAll method... this is too much effort for such rare occurrences of characters.